# Using QGIS C++ API?

Tags: qgis, c++

I'm trying to create a simple application using QGIS SDK. But currently, I'm stuck with API at very beginning stage.

belows are the env.

Windows 7

MSVC 2015

QGIS SDK (downlaod by OSGeo4w) include:
    qgis-dev(3.2.3)
    Qt5(5.9)

[image: here is the OSGeo4W directory]

[image: here is the OSGeo4W-app directory]

And start by create an empty project, property settings:

C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories

```
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\include
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\include\QtCore
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\include\QtGui
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\include\QtWidgets
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\include\QtXml
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-dev\include
C:\OSGeo4W\include
```

Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories

```
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\lib
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-dev\lib
```

Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

```
qtmaind.lib
Qt5Cored.lib
Qt5Guid.lib
Qt5Widgetsd.lib
qgis_core.lib
qgis_app.lib
qgis_gui.lib
```

The test code is quite simple:

main.cpp

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <qgsapplication.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     QgsApplication a(argc, argv, true);
 //  QgsApplication::setPrefixPath("C:/path/to/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", true);
 //  QgsApplication::initQgis();
 //  ImageViewer w; 
 //  w.show();

     return a.exec(); 
}
```

however, errors occured when I build it,

(1)no instance of constructor "QgsMapUnitScale::QgsMapUnitScale" matches the argument list  (qgsrendercontext.h)

(2)"M_PI": undeclared identifier (qgsabstractgeometry.h)

[image: here is the build errors]

Could anyone give me a suggestion?

I have some difficulties to understand how the API should work and there is really few doc. and resource about 
QGIS C++ developement on internet, even on QGIS offical website.

Comment: Developing QGIS plugins in C++ is discouraged which would be why there is limited documentation... there is some logic to this, making your own branch is no problem but your plugin development stops with you then the next time there's an update your version is out-of-date and you have to redo *all* your changes again to get the benefit of the update. I think it would be nice to have this capability, or C# even, but this decision was made early on in the QGIS project and doesn't look like changing soon.

Answer (score 1):

For the "M_PI": undeclared identifier (qgsabstractgeometry.h) just go the the header file and add `#define M_PI 3.14159265359` below the #include files

Comment: Please consider building on your answer to provide more explanation and references. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

For the "M_PI": undeclared identifier, you can put these two line of code at the top of the `main.cpp`:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
```